# Python sum only number in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to sum only number in  list , my list contain also characters what is best way?
I try this

```py
x = ['0.1₾', '0.1₾', '2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '5₾', '2₾', '9.9₾', '0.7₾', '5₾', '0.9₾', '0.8₾', '0.2₾', '1₾', '0.2₾', '3₾', '0.3₾', '5₾', '0.1₾', '2₾', '0.8₾', '1₾']
y = 0
for i in x:
    y += float(i)
print(y)
```

but error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.1₾'
```

what is best solution ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the character always appears as the last character in every element in the array, you can use the substring method to isolate the float part of each element

All you would need to change in your code is instead of:

```
y += float(i)
```

use:

```
y += float((i[0:len(i) - 1]))
```

If you want to use negative indexing:

```
y += float((i[0:-1]))
```

Either of the options above work :)

Comment: there is an index: `-1` which is the last item in iterable so might as well do sth like: `[0:-1]`

Comment: I know, I just think that without using negative indexing is slightly easier to read, I'll include both :))

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
x = ['0.1₾', '0.1₾', '2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '5₾', '2₾', '9.9₾', '0.7₾', '5₾', '0.9₾', '0.8₾', '0.2₾', '1₾', '0.2₾', '3₾', '0.3₾', '5₾', '0.1₾', '2₾', '0.8₾', '1₾']
print(sum(map(lambda y:float(y.replace("₾","")),x)))
# 41.3
```

We are just replacing the `₾` to empty and changing string to float and doing sum using `sum` function!

For more information about `sum` function you can visit [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sum) and for `map` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: all is great and stuff, but you could add maybe a bit more explanation or at least some sources for the OP to better understand what is going on (more about the `map` function)

Comment: @Matiiss yeah! I have added!!

Comment: You don't need the `list`. `sum` will execute on a `map`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get rid of the ₾ symbol.

This will work :

```
y = 0
for string in x:
    y += float(string[:-1])
print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly brittle, but works fine:

```
x = ['0.1₾', '0.1₾', '2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '5₾', '2₾', '9.9₾', '0.7₾', '5₾', '0.9₾', '0.8₾', '0.2₾', '1₾', '0.2₾', '3₾', '0.3₾', '5₾', '0.1₾', '2₾', '0.8₾', '1₾']
y = 0
for i in x:
    y += float(i.split('₾')[0])
print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to extract simple float and int numbers:

```
# import re
>>> sum([float(re.findall(r'([+-]?(?:[0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)', s)[0]) for s in x])
41.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short solution using list [comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```py
total = sum([float(f.replace('₾', '')) for f in x])
# or the variant using string slices
total = sum([float(f[:-1]) for f in x])
# we only convert the string without the last character
```

Where x is your list and total is the sum of all float values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the problem:

```py
x = ['0.1₾', '0.1₾', '2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '5₾', '2₾', '9.9₾', '0.7₾', '5₾', '0.9₾', '0.8₾', '0.2₾', '1₾', '0.2₾', '3₾', '0.3₾', '5₾', '0.1₾', '2₾', '0.8₾', '1₾']
print(sum([float(a.replace('₾', '')) for a in x]))
```

it is pretty short, but it works, basically it `print`s the `sum` of a list that is made up of `float` values from a string in which `'₾'` is basically removed by leaving just the number and so for each item in `x`, in short: a simple list comprehension.

could also use any of the following inside the `float()` (in this case at least):

```py
a.split('₾')[0]
a[0:-1]  # a[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to find the [printable representation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/repr) for special character using: `print repr(x[0])`

Just need to add code to replace the special character:

```
x = ['0.1₾', '0.1₾', '2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '0.2₾', '5₾', '2₾', '9.9₾', '0.7₾', '5₾', '0.9₾', '0.8₾', '0.2₾', '1₾', '0.2₾', '3₾', '0.3₾', '5₾', '0.1₾', '2₾', '0.8₾', '1₾']
y = 0
for i in x:
    a = i.replace('₾','')
    y += float(a)

print(y)
```

```
>>> print(y)
41.3
```